# Nested multicols with column separation line only in the most outer layer in LaTeX

Tags: multicol

I am using the multicols environment with 3 columns in my document (the main multicols). I managed to get the line separation between the columns with `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}` inside the `\begin{multicols*}{3}`environment.

Now I need to use a nested multicols environment inside the main multicols that does not have the line separation. I tried to use `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}` inside the nested multicols but there appears nevertheless a separation line in the nested multicols. How can I draw the separation line only in the main multicols but not in the nested ones?

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 6pt, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
     Here follows some text with a separation line between the columns...
     \begin{multicols*}{2}
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
       Text in the nested multicols that should be without separation lines...
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
     \end{multicols*}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the column rule should be specified _before_ you start multicols, but also please provide a proper test file yours is incomplete and has undefined commands such as `\setlenght`

Comment: Sorry for the misstyping of the `\setlength`command. I updated the code so it can be compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not always easy to find out, when the columns of `multicols` environments are really set. Moving the `\setlength` commands outside the inner `multicols` environment solves your problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 6pt, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
     Here follows some text with a separation line between the columns...
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
     \begin{multicols*}{2}
       Text in the nested multicols that should be without separation lines...
     \end{multicols*}
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
     \lipsum
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactely what I needed. This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are doing this frequently it might be more convenient to create a custom environment that will automatically restore the outer rule length with a local group.

```
\newenvironment{innermulticol}[1]
    {\begingroup\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\begin{multicols*}{#1}}
    {\end{multicols*}\endgroup}
```

You will have less trouble if you decide to change the rule length of the outer columns afterwards.